# Getting argument error while converting set to list

Tags: python, list, set

I have a set that I am trying to convert to a list, but I get `Error in argument: u'(different_aois)'`

```
ipdb> l = list(different_aois)
*** Error in argument: u'= list(different_aois)'
ipdb> type(different_aois)
<type 'set'>
ipdb> list(different_aois)
*** Error in argument: u'(different_aois)'
```

Comment: What does `different_aois` look like?

Comment: What is `different_aois`? Can you show us what `print(different_aois)` prints?

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: The `ipdb` header suggests that you're not in an ordinary REPL, but rather in an [interactive debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) prompt. You can't enter arbitrary python statements into a debugger. Try quitting the prompt (perhaps with the q key), and re-enter your REPL normally.

Comment: @Kevin: you are right. I was in the debugger mode and modifying existing objects so it was not working.

Answer (score 17):

In pure python this should work. It `ipdb`, `list` is a command that overrides the normal python `list`. See https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/issues/106, which mentions that you should write it as

```
!l = list(different_aois)
```